# using react-native-fused-location returning nothing at all

Tags: react-native

i am using react-native-android-location-enabler to enable the gps so we can get the user location ..
here is what i did

`RNAndroidLocationEnabler.promptForEnableLocationIfNeeded({interval:10000,fastInterval: 5000})
            .then(async (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                try {
                    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, {
                            title: 'App needs to access your location',
                            message: 'App needs access to your location ' +
                            'so we can let our app be even more awesome.'
                        }
                    );
                    if (granted == PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        FusedLocation.setLocationPriority(FusedLocation.Constants.HIGH_ACCURACY);
                        const location = await FusedLocation.getFusedLocation();
                        console.log(location);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Not granted');
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log('err',err);
                }
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });`

if the gps is off before this code it will ask to turn it on then the fusedLocation doesn't return anything at all ( not error even ) ... if the the gps is previously turned on the fusedLocation works just fine .

```
"react-native": "0.54.2",
"react-native-android-location-enabler": "^1.0.5",
"react-native-fused-location": "^0.2.1",
"react-native-maps": "https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps.git"
```